# Adding new line to console output

Tags: vb.net

In console application we write the statement as

```
Console.WriteLine("the addition is {0}",i)
```

it gives the output

> addition is 50

Now my question is: I want the answer to appear like this:

> addition is
>
> 50

How I will assign the output to the next line?

Comment: Could you rephrase? Can't make out what you are trying to say. (or use point and comma's?)

Comment: Please take a moment to look at my reformat of your question. Note that while you are entering the question, the preview area (below the area where you type your question) shows you what the formatting will end up looking like.

Answer (score 9):

```
Console.WriteLine("The addition is, {0} {1}", _
    Environment.NewLine, i)
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree with rdkleine. Punctuation in your question would be very helpful. But, I'm going to step out on a limb and assume you mean, how can I add a line break to the output using Console.WriteLine.

Use vbcrlf to generate a line break.

```
Console.WriteLine("The addition is" & vbCrLf & "{0}", i)
```

Comment: It will be better practice (and more efficient) to insert all values that is not part of the string constant as parameters, like dbasnett did in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317223/adding-new-line-to-console-output/3318450#3318450). So if you want to use `vbCrLf` instead of `Environment.NewLine`, it would be:   `Console.WriteLine("The addition is{0} {1}", vbCrLf, i)`

Comment: Site your source for better practice.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Josaph, but I would do so like this:

```
Console.Writeline("The addition is{0}", vbCrLf & i)
```

Comment: It will be better practice (and more efficient) to insert all values that is not part of the string constant as parameters, like dbasnett did in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317223/adding-new-line-to-console-output/3318450#3318450). So if you want to use `vbCrLf` instead of `Environment.NewLine`, it would be:   `Console.WriteLine("The addition is{0} {1}", vbCrLf, i)`